# Is it safe to save root login/password for Webmin in browser?

Tags: administrator, root, administration, webmin, virtualmin

Is it safe to save root login/password for Webmin in browser? I mean the autosave login feature in most browsers. I'm using Chrome on my own PC.

Comment: It depends. Shared PC? Not safe. Your own PC? Possibly safe. Never 100% safe. The question here is really is it "safe enough" - which we can't answer without making some assumptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Chromium-based browsers on Windows OS AFAIK (on all I know) passwords are stored encrypted and can only be reviewed by entering the users Windows login password. So if you have your own Windows login user with save password, then it can be assumed relatively save, comparable to a dedicated password manager. As already mentioned it is all relative and depends on how you generally handle your passwords and how sensitive the server is that you are controlling via Webmin. However if you use Webmin at all (instead of SSH with pubkey access) it should be acceptable since granting root/admin access to any web application introduces a security risk on its own.

However the above applies for Chromium-based browsers. E.g. on Firefox by default any user can review the passwords, but they are about to change the default currently. Until then one can manually add a master password, although I cannot say something about how secure (encryption/algorithm-wise) this is: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/use-master-password-protect-stored-logins

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest to use a password manager like lastpass through which you can access your password on all major browser and devices .

Comment: How trustworthy is lastpass? Has it ever been compromised before?

Comment: @cilapo1541:LastPass experienced a single security incident in our 10-year history, back in 2015. Bottom line, no encrypted vault data was compromised" [What Happens if LastPass Gets Hacked | Our Security Model](https://www.lastpass.com/security/what-if-lastpass-gets-hacked)